# Layout changes might have made component "Detect Insert and Update insert" invalid SSIS programmatically

Tags: c#, ssis

I got this strange message "Layout changes might have made component "Detect Insert and Update insert" (70) invalid." While i try to attach two SSIS component with this code :
    path.AttachPathAndPropagateNotifications(srcHSTGComponent.OutputCollection[0], splitComponent.InputCollection[0]);

Comment: Do you get this message as an Exception? In such case it is strange, no such template in SSIS Exceptions described in [MSDN ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345164(v=sql.120).aspx). Could you elaborate more on error details.

Answer (score 0):

This error message come from the exception management in the pipe,just don't capture the exception and the program work just fine.